# Creating a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating an iphone app using storyboard. I'm basically new on objective c and Xcode.

I have a list of categories, every time I click on a category it should open a tableView, so I can add an item in that category. But instead of getting a different tableView for each category, its the same table for all the categories and the added items are copied.

How can I create a new table for each label?

Thanks in advance!

Here's what I have for adding a category

```
@interface ListViewController ()

@end

@implementation ListViewController{
    NSMutableArray *items;
}



@synthesize lists;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
    List *item = [[List alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Grocery List";
    [items addObject:item];

    item = [[List alloc]init];
    item.title = @"Project List";
    [items addObject:item];

    item = [[List alloc] init];
    item.title = @"Events List";
    [items addObject:item];

    self.lists = items;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.lists count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    // Configure the cell...

    /*UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListsCell"];

    List *list = [self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = list.title;*/

    ListCell *cell = (ListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListsCell"];

    List *list = [self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.titleLabel.text = list.title;

    return cell;

}

//Add new list, new row will be added on the bottom and its data source must always be sync
-(void)addViewControllerSave:(AddViewController *)controller addList:(List *)list{

    [self.lists addObject:list];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.lists count] - 1 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){

            [self.lists removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }   

   /* else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }*/   
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation
*/

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddList"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddViewController *addViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        addViewController.delegate = self;
    }

    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewItem"]){
        UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;

        ItemViewController *itemViewController = [[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        itemViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}



#pragma mark - AddViewControllerDelegate
-(void)addViewControllerCancel:(AddViewController *)controller{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)addViewControllerSave:(AddViewController *)controller{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)itemViewControllerBack:(ItemViewController *)controller{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Here's what I have for adding an item:

```
@interface ItemViewController ()

@end

@implementation ItemViewController{
    NSMutableArray *newItems;
}

@synthesize items;

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    newItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

   Item *i = [[Item alloc]init];

    i.listItem = @"a";
    [newItems addObject:i];

    self.items = newItems;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell...

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemsCell"];

    Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = item.listItem;

    return cell;
}

-(void)addIteViewControllerSave:(AddItemViewController *)controller addItem:(Item *)item{

    [self.items addObject:item];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.items count] -1 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}



#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddItemViewController *addItemViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];

        addItemViewController.itemDelegate = self;
    }
}

#pragma mark - AddItemViewControllerDelegate
-(void)addItemviewControllerCancel:(AddItemViewController *)controller{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)addIteViewControllerSave:(AddItemViewController *)controller{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - ItemViewControllerDelegate
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate itemViewControllerBack:self];
}



@end
```

AddItemViewController

```
#import "AddItemViewController.h"
#import "Item.h"

@interface AddItemViewController ()


@end

@implementation AddItemViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{
    [self.itemDelegate addItemviewControllerCancel:self];
}

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
    Item *item = [[Item alloc] init];

    item.listItem = self.listItemTextField.text;

    [self.itemDelegate addIteViewControllerSave:self addItem:item];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new table view for each label, instead populate it with different data for each label, you will need to change the object you are storing your data in and call

`[tableView reloadData];`

If all the added items you may need to clear out your array you are using to store the objects before adding the additional content.

```
[self.items removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: I'm still confuse, but how do I create a new viewController each time, I create a new list category?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new tableViewController each time you select a category, create it once and then just repopulate the data in the table. I'm a little confused as to your process so let me state it and tell me if I have made the wrong assumptions.(We will use food for an example) You have a List of categories (which would contain a table view with the following rows Meats, Vegetables, fruits). When you click a category for example fruit you want a new table view to display (apple, orange, banana etc)

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your question. You won't need to create a new viewController for each new category, you will just need to create the data for that category.Then call it on the same viewController you are using for the other categories (remembering to make sure you reload the table view and its associated data).

Comment: I tried your advice and created an array and load it to a viewController. I used NSArray to add multiple items on each category but how can I do it so when I press the plus sign it will add an item?

Comment: Give that button an action [plusButton addTarget:self @selector(methodToAddNewItem) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
Inside methodToAddNewItem add an item to that array  (you will want to be using NSMutableArray so you can access the method addObject:) and then after adding the object you want to reload your tables.

Comment: I change it to NSMutable Array and its loading the data but when I try to add, it will add the data but when I click the category again the added data is gone. How do I actually reload the tables? [self.tableview reloadData] but it gives out an error.

Comment: The errors are gone but [self.tableview reloadData]  doesn't do anything, I added that line on viewLoad.

Comment: If you add it in viewDidLoad it will only be called when the view is loaded (normally once under normal circumstances). You will need to call it every time you change the array of data the table is using.